# Como solucionar Column not found: 1054 Unknown column en Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Recibo el error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column al querer trabajar con una relación que sé que está mal hecha debido al nombre que utilice, busque varias soluciones pero en mi caso no funcionan.

No quiero abusar de la generosidad de la comunidad, pero estaría necesitando una orientación:

**CÓDIGO PROPERTY**

**1) Migracion Property**

```
$table->foreignId('tipoDePropiedad_id')->references('id')->on('tipoDePropiedad')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

**2) Modelo Property**

```
 protected $table = 'properties';
 protected $fillable = [
      'nombre_propiedad', 'precio_propiedad', 'user_id', 'category_id', 'tipodepropiedad_id'
 ];
```

**3) Relación Property**

```
public function tipo_propiedad(){
    return $this->hasMany(TipoDePropiedad::class);
}
```

**CÓDIGO TIPODEPROPIEDAD**

**1) Migracion TipoDePropiedad**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tipoDePropiedad', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('tipo_propiedad');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**2) Modelo**

```
    protected $table = 'tipoDePropiedad';
    protected $fillable = [
        'tipo_propiedad'
    ];
public function properties(){
        return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
    }
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```
$pro = Property::with('tipo_propiedad')->get();
```

Comprendo que la clave foranea no es localizada por Eloquent Laravel por lo tanto agregué sin éxito en  el modelo tipodepropiedad.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'tipoDePropiedad_id';
```

Y en la relación el parámetro string

```
public function tipo_propiedad(){
    return $this->hasOne(TipoDePropiedad::class, 'tipoDePropiedad_id');
}
```

Y no logro detectar como puedo solucionar este error.

**EDICIÓN**

Una propiedad tiene un tipodepropiedad

Tipo de propiedad:
Casa - Departamento - Local

Y un tipoDePropiedad tiene muchas propiedades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu modelo tiene una columna que no existe.

Primer paso: Actualizar tu Modelo `Property`.

```
// La columna es en mayúsculas
protected $fillable = [
      ..., 'tipoDePropiedad_id'
 ];

public function tipo_propiedad()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoDePropiedad', 'tipoDePropiedad_id');
}
```

Segundo paso: Actualizar tu Modelo `TipoDePropiedad`.

```
public function propiedades()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Property', 'tipoDePropiedad_id');
}
```

**Edit:**

Debes borrar esto, ya que no hay ninguna `primaryKey` con ese nombre.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'tipoDePropiedad_id';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfecto!! que alegría!!

Comment: marca la respuesta como correcta si te funciono @maraet

Comment: Listo gracias!!